# ActionScript play audio

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, headless

I am just trying to make a simple .swf file that plays a piece of audio when it loads. This compiles but when I bring it up into the browser nothing happens. I could only find sprite based tutorials so I took a stab that you can extend Sound the same way as you would extend Sprite. The final version is going to be headless and called my Java Script to play audio on Events.

```
   package {
            import flash.media.Sound;
            import flash.net.URLRequest;

            public class typeRight extends Sound {
                    public function HelloWorld( ) {
                    load(new URLRequest('./sound.mp3'));
                    play();
                    }
            }
    }
```

I am NOT working in Flash so please no GUI advice ; )

Comment: It's worth noting for your future projects, Sprite and MovieClip (or subclasses thereof) are pretty much the only two classes you can use as a document basis for a SWF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than subclassing the Sound class, create a document class like this that contains a Sound class in it:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class SoundPlayer extends Sprite
    {
        protected var _sound : Sound;
        protected var _channel : SoundChannel;

        public function SoundPlayer()
        {
            _sound = new Sound();
            _sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundLoadCompleteHandler);
            _sound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loadError);
            _sound.load(new URLRequest("./sound.mp3"));
        }

        protected function soundLoadCompleteHandler(evt : Event) : void
        {
            // Use the _channel object to control sound properties such as pan and volume.
            _channel = _sound.play();
        }

        protected function loadError(evt : IOErrorEvent) : void
        {
            trace ("ERROR :: " + evt);
            // You could try recovering from the error here.
        }

    }
}
```